# Is it possible to change the default advertising interval in BlueZ?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I've already created a GATT server using the instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52982329/11828925). The only problem with this server is the fact that it advertises using the default advertising interval used by BlueZ (1.288s), which is too slow for my application.

I have also tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21124993/11828925) to decrease the advertising interval. While the method described in this case works fine, the resulting advertising intervals DO NOT persist when I try to start the GATT server again in `bluetoothctl`, and the default 1.288s advertising interval is used again upon starting the GATT server.

My question is, is there a way around this problem? Could the advertising parameters set using the `hcitool` be saved as the default parameters of advertising? In the worst case, is it possible to recompile BlueZ with a shorter advertising interval?

Comment: We care not what you read on the Internet. We care about the actual commands you ran, and their actual results, properly formatted. Help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo desired value to the following two files:

```
/sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/adv_min_interval
/sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/adv_max_interval
```

where hci0 is your bt/ble device. Adv. interval is calculated as value * 0.625ms

You need to have CONFIG_BT_DEBUGFS=y in your kernel configuration for this to work.

This works on bluez-5.50, not sure about previous releases.